# How to set runtime version in Google Cloud Buildpacks when using Functions Framework for Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Functions Framework to build my function using `pack`.

```
$ls -lah .
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  9 viroos  staff   288B Oct 18 02:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 viroos  staff   288B Oct 11 03:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 viroos  staff    44B Oct 17 19:37 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 viroos  staff     6B Oct 18 02:24 .python-version
drwxr-xr-x  3 viroos  staff    96B Oct 17 22:44 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 viroos  staff    32B Oct 18 02:54 main.py
-rw-r--r--  1 viroos  staff   259B Oct 18 02:54 project.toml
-rw-r--r--  1 viroos  staff    75B Oct 18 02:20 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x  6 viroos  staff   192B Oct 17 19:35 venv
```

```
$ cat project.toml 
[[build.env]]
name =  "GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION"
value = "python38"
[[build.env]]
name = "GOOGLE_FUNCTION_TARGET"
value = "foo"
[[build.env]]
name = "GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE"
value = "event"
[[build.env]]
name = "GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE"
```

```
$ cat .python-version 
3.8.6
```

I get following error when I try to build the function:

```
$ pack build foo --builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1v1: Pulling from buildpacks/builder
Digest: sha256:75f77739e5f8b6e06ff24ca56382de6ef44fce4d5def89dbde04fff5f8c95567
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1
v1: Pulling from buildpacks/gcp/run
Digest: sha256:5c9214c1500035542b066d9fe8e4b5643c9b52388f52f543e91f55b8ebb27bc9
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/buildpacks/gcp/run:v1
===> DETECTING
4 of 5 buildpacks participating
google.python.runtime             0.9.1
google.python.functions-framework 0.9.1
google.python.pip                 0.9.1
google.utils.label                0.0.1
===> ANALYZING
Previous image with name "foo" not found
===> RESTORING
===> BUILDING
=== Python - Runtime (google.python.runtime@0.9.1) ===
Using runtime version from GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION: python38
Failure: (ID: d1f5dcf5) Runtime version python38 does not exist at https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-buildpacks/python/python-python38.tar.gz (status 403). You can specify the version with GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorry your project couldn't be built.
Our documentation explains ways to configure Buildpacks to better recognise your project:
 -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/blob/main/README.md
If you think you've found an issue, please report it:
 -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/new
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 145
```

When I delete

```
[[build.env]]
name =  "GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION"
value = "python38"
```

from `project.toml` I get following error:

```
$ pack build foo --builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1
v1: Pulling from buildpacks/builder
Digest: sha256:75f77739e5f8b6e06ff24ca56382de6ef44fce4d5def89dbde04fff5f8c95567
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1
v1: Pulling from buildpacks/gcp/run
Digest: sha256:5c9214c1500035542b066d9fe8e4b5643c9b52388f52f543e91f55b8ebb27bc9
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/buildpacks/gcp/run:v1
===> DETECTING
4 of 5 buildpacks participating
google.python.runtime             0.9.1
google.python.functions-framework 0.9.1
google.python.pip                 0.9.1
google.utils.label                0.0.1
===> ANALYZING
Previous image with name "foo" not found
===> RESTORING
===> BUILDING
=== Python - Runtime (google.python.runtime@0.9.1) ===
Using runtime version from .python-version: 3.8.6
Failure: (ID: 8d3064d0) Runtime version 3.8.6 does not exist at https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-buildpacks/python/python-3.8.6.tar.gz (status 403). You can specify the version with GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorry your project couldn't be built.
Our documentation explains ways to configure Buildpacks to better recognise your project:
 -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/blob/main/README.md
If you think you've found an issue, please report it:
 -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/new
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 145
```

Questions:

1. What is the correct/easiest/recommended way for managing python
   runtime version in this scenario?
2. What is the correct value for
   `GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION`?
3. Is there any place where I can find list
   of all runtime versions?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the errors you're experiencing and here's what I observed:

---

As advised by Dustin, in order to use **Python 3.8.6**, it should be enough to specify it in the `.python-version` file:

```
3.8.6
```

In `project.toml`, however, you can also specify it the following way:

```
[[build.env]]
name =  "GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION"
value = "3.8.6"
```

---

Regarding the [available versions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks#general-builder-and-buildpacks), buildpacks support **Python 3.7+** although `3.8.6` seems to be the highest supported version.

I've also tested it with versions `3.8.4`, `3.8.0`, `3.7.7`, `3.7.2` and `3.7.0` to confirm that, and it's been successful for me, while `3.9.0` and versions lower than `3.7.0` were leading to the same error: *"Runtime version does not exist"*.

---

The other error you were experiencing *("Sorry your project couldn't be built")* when deleting `GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION` in `project.toml` seems to be related to your `GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE` setting as you haven't specified the **value** for it:

```
[[build.env]]
name = "GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE"
```

The error was gone once I added the value. E.g.

```
[[build.env]]
name = "GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE"
value = "main.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

The availability of a given runtime lags a bit behind the Python release it corresponds to. You should find that 3.8.6 is now available.

> What is the correct/easiest/recommended way for managing python runtime version in this scenario?

Setting `.python-version` to a value like `3.8.6` is the recommended way.

> What is the correct value for GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION?

This would be the same as what you'd put in `.python-version`, but would take precedence over it.

> Is there any place where I can find list of all runtime versions?

Unfortunately not at this time, but you can file an issue at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks to request this.