# Specify Python version on Cloud Run Buildpack

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am deploying a web app on Cloud Run using the automated Cloud Build "Buildpack" option (as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf3KAY-i6zw&t=495s)); hence not having to create a Docker File.

I would like to deploy the app using python-3.8.12 and buildpacks.
How can I specify that?

Comment: Can you try to add a `runtime.txt` file with that content `python-3.8.12`? And let me know. (it's possible that python-3.8.13 is the only one supported, try it is the build version is not important.)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on GCP; just tried. Any other option? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no need to specify it. [The builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks#general-builder-and-buildpacks) attempts to autodetect the language of your source code and Python 3.7+ is one of the supported languages.

You may try this [Python buildpacks sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpack-samples/tree/master/sample-functions-framework-python).

You can also find out deeper information about buildpacks in [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suhCr5W_bFc).

**Update**

As an alternative, you can also manually specify which buildpack to use, thereby skipping the auto-detection step. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64408792/how-to-set-runtime-version-in-google-cloud-buildpacks-when-using-functions-frame), you can also specify it in the `project.toml` the following way:

```
[[build.env]] 
name = "GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION" 
value = "3.8.6"
```

This would be the same as what you'd put in the `.python-version`, but would take precedence over it.

Comment: Thank you; I need to specify the version, for some dependencies issues. Any alternative option?

Comment: Yes, in my update you’ll find an alternative

Answer (score 4):

You only need to add *.python-version* file to your repository, in which the Python version is reported as:

```
3.8.6
```

Comment: Very insightful!!!